# SymmetricDS Sample - client node refused to connect to server node

Tags: database-connection, symmetricds

I am working on the example from the SymmetricDS tutorial. I am using the configuration files corp-000.properties and store-001.properties found in the samples directory of the download zip. I have placed them in the engine directory and edited them so that corp-000 is using a ***Postgresql DB*** as ***master-000*** and store-001 is using an ***MySQL DB*** as ***slave-001***, both on separate machine.

Here are the config from corp-000.properties:

```
engine.name=master-000
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/master?stringtype=unspecified
```

I've also enable the firewall (8080/tcp and 5432/tcp) and changed port from 31415 to 8080: However when  the same error still came out and the url returns this result:

```
This site can’t be reached

<Master-node-IP> refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What should I do to solve thise problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add to corp configuration

```
auto.registration=true
```

Can’t hurt to add

```
auto.reload=true
```

Solution by @swm is

> The solution is need to set bind ip in symmetricDS

Comment: both initially have been added in config. but same error happens

Comment: Could the corp server be reached on port 8080 from client machine? telnet master_node_ip 8080, for example

Comment: Connection refused. Not sure how solve this. Am I missed any config?

Comment: Check if the corp application is running and listening to port 8080

Comment: Port is not connected. But I've opened port (enable firewall 8080). but when netstat -lntu, 8080 port is not listen

Comment: ok when I trigger bin/sym. the corp listen to 127.0.0.1:8080, and in store , <corp-ip>:8080. how to change that they listen to 0.0.0.0:8080 instead? this probably causes the conn issue

Comment: Use the external IP of both machines

Comment: The solution is need to set bind ip in symmetricDS

Answer (score 0):

Below are some example configs.

What is happening here is that the main or master cannot see the sync / registration urls and ports not the database.

Make sure the following are setup correctly.

MAIN

```
registration.url=
sync.url=ttp://<IP>:<PORT>/sync/<SDS_MAIN>
```

CHILD

```
registration.url=http://<IP>:<PORT>/sync/<SDS_MAIN>
sync.url=http://<IP>:<PORT>/sync/<SDS_CHILD>
```

FULL EXAMPLE CONFIGS BELOW

MAIN

```
engine.name=<SDS_MAIN>

db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<IP>:1433/<DB>;useCursors=true;bufferMaxMemory=10240;lobBuffer=5242880
db.user=***********
db.password=***********

registration.url=
sync.url=ttp://<IP>:<PORT>/sync/<SDS_MAIN>

group.id=<GID>
external.id=000

auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true

sync.table.prefix=sym
#start.initial.load.extract.job=false

compression.level=-1
compression.strategy=0
```

CHILD

```
engine.name=<SDS_CHILD>

db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<IP>:1433/<DB>;useCursors=true;bufferMaxMemory=10240;lobBuffer=5242880
db.user=***********
db.password=***********

registration.url=http://<IP>:<PORT>/sync/<SDS_MAIN>
sync.url=http://<IP>:<PORT>/sync/<SDS_CHILD>

group.id=<GID>
external.id=100

auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true

sync.table.prefix=sym
start.initial.load.extract.job=false

compression.level=-1
compression.strategy=0
```